# Как вывести переменную на экран reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Есть переменная `now`, в которой записаны дата и время. Как мне вывести эту переменную на экран?

```
export function Data() {
let now = new Date();
console.log(now)
}
```

---

```
import './App.css';
import {Example} from './usestate'
import {Data} from './date'
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
  <Example></Example>
    <Data></Data>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Такую переменную на экран не вывести... Можно вызвать функцию (правда она вернет undefined)...

Comment: Или нужно в консоль чтобы получился вывод? Тогда сделай так - вместо `<Data></Data>` напиши `<p>{Data()}</p>`

Comment: В функциях принято писать `return` потому что `console.log` используется чаще всего только для логирования каких-то значений, но не возврата.

Answer (score 0):

> Для вывода значения на экран из функции, можно воспользоваться следующими способами

###### Вернуть JSX элемент из фукнции

```
function Data() {
  let now = new Date();
  return <>{now.toString()}</>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Example></Example>
      <Data></Data>
    </div>
  );
}
```

###### Отрендерить значение, возвращаемое фукнций

```
function Data() {
  let now = new Date();
  return now.toString();
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Example></Example>
      {Data()}
    </div>
  );
}
```